# fprintf in c erase th firs character char of the next line

Tags: c, printf, scanf

i have a function, it write in file but when i update my file, i can see the line i have updated erase the first char of the next line. I saw thiw proceed when the number is >= 10...
`

```
void addPieceToFile(Piece* p, char* file){
    FILE* f  = fopen(file, "rw+");

    int nbrSalles = 0;
    int id = 0;
    int test;

    if(f != NULL) {

        fseek(f,0, SEEK_END);
        if(ftell(f) == 0){  //Premier passage ici si le fichier est vide
            fprintf(f,"{%d}\n",nbrSalles += 1);

            fprintf(f,"[%d|%d]%d\n",p->height, p->width, p->id);

            for(int i = 0; i < p->height; i +=1 ){
                for(int j = 0; j < p->width; j +=1 ){
                    fprintf(f,"%c ",p->piece[i][j]);
                }
                fprintf(f,"\n");
            }
        }else{  //Si le fichier contient déja une ou plusieur pieces on rentre ici
            rewind(f);  // On remonte au début du fichier
            fscanf(f,"{%d}\n",&nbrSalles);  // On récupère le nombre de salles
            fscanf(f,"[%d|%d]%d\n",&p->height, &p->width, &id);  // On récupère le nombre de salles
            fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);    // On revient a la fin du fichier ppour ecrire la nouvelle salle

            test = testeChaine(TEMP_FILE,file);

            if(test==1){
                fprintf(f,"[%d|%d]%d\n",p->height, p->width, p->id); // On garde l'id actuelle en cas de modification

            }else{
                fprintf(f,"[%d|%d]%d\n",p->height, p->width, p->id+nbrSalles); // On met à jour l'id
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < p->height; i +=1 ){
                for(int j = 0; j < p->width; j +=1 ){
                    fprintf(f,"%c ",p->piece[i][j]);
                }
                fprintf(f,"\n");
            }

            rewind(f);    // On revient en haut du fichier
            nbrSalles = nbrSalles + 1;
            fprintf(f,"{%d}",nbrSalles); // Et on met à jour le nombre de salles I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        }
        system("clear");
        result("Piece ajoutée.");
    }else{
        system("clear");
        printf("Error. %s\n",file);
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

`

I want to avoid this bug.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: To allow others to help you debug the problem, please supply a [mre].

Comment: "I saw thiw proceed when the number is >= 10" Seems obvious; the next line of text will not mysteriously shift one character to the right to make room for the extra digit. Please be aware there is no such thing as 'lines' in a text file; it is just a long sequence of characters, some of which are newline characters.

Comment: Jonathan, BTW, `fclose(f);` is called, even when `f== NULL`. Don't do that.

Comment: Ok thank you, the only way to avoid this is to add a "\n" but i don't think this is the good way

Comment: Jonathan, better code check the return  value from each `fscanf()` call.  It may even point to the bug.